# Output from INSERT INTO Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure where I first insert a new row in a table. The ID that is generated by this query is then needed for another query. Is it possible to access the prevoisly generated ID with the use of OUTPUT?

This is what I have done so far and it is pretty much a guess that didnt work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addApp]

      @Name varchar(50) 
    , @logoUrl varchar(150)
    , @siteUrl varchar(150)
    , @userId int
    , @canvasWidth int
    , @canvasHeight int

AS
DECLARE @tempId INT
SET @tempid = INSERT INTO AppInfo (name, logoUrl, userId) 
              OUTPUT inserted.id 
              VALUES(@Name, @logoUrl, @userId);
INSERT INTO CanvasApps (id, siteUrl, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
OUTPUT inserted.id
VALUES(@tempid, @siteUrl, @logoUrl, @userId);
```

Comment: Why would you guess when there is documentation and hundreds of examples around?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't find any for me good example on how to use OUTPUT in this case. Now I got a perfect answer that hopefully also will help someone else. Peace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can even do it in single statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addApp] 

      @Name VARCHAR(50)
    , @logoUrl VARCHAR(150)
    , @siteUrl VARCHAR(150)
    , @userId INT
    , @canvasWidth INT
    , @canvasHeight INT

AS BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.AppInfo (name, logoUrl, userId) 
    OUTPUT Inserted.ID, @siteUrl, @canvasWidth , @canvasHeight
       INTO dbo.CanvasApps (id, siteUrl, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
    VALUES (@Name, @logoUrl, @userId)

END
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this one -

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addApp] 

      @Name VARCHAR(50)
    , @logoUrl VARCHAR(150)
    , @siteUrl VARCHAR(150)
    , @userId INT
    , @canvasWidth INT
    , @canvasHeight INT

AS BEGIN

    DECLARE @tempId INT

    INSERT INTO dbo.AppInfo (name, logoUrl, userId) 
    SELECT @Name, @logoUrl, @userId

    SELECT @tempId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    INSERT INTO dbo.CanvasApps (id, siteUrl, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) 
    SELECT @tempId, @siteUrl, @logoUrl, @userId

END
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try this after your insert statement and use this varible into second insert statement.:-

```
SET @BVar=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the results of `output` into a table rather than just a scalar variable:

```
declare @tempId table (
    id int
)

INSERT INTO AppInfo (name, logoUrl, userId) 
       OUTPUT inserted.id into @tempId 
              VALUES(@Name, @logoUrl, @userId);
```

Comment: Curious that you demonstrate by creating a table that _is_ a variable after saying that `OUTPUT` can't go to a variable.

Comment: There is a difference between a scalar variable and a table variable.

Comment: Agreed.  The first line of your answer should make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the following variable:

```
@@IDENTITY
```

Comment: You should use [`@@scope_Identity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx) As this is limited to the current scope where as `@@Identity` is not.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a place where `@@IDENTITY` was the solution except creating salt for a hash.  `Scope_Identity()` is allegedly fixed and `OUTPUT` is more generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[addApp] 
  @Name varchar(50),  
  @logoUrl varchar(150), 
  @siteUrl varchar(150), 
  @userId int, 
  @canvasWidth int, 
  @canvasHeight int
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  INSERT dbo.AppInfo (name, logoUrl, userId) 
    OUTPUT inserted.id, @siteUrl, @canvasWidth, @canvasHeight
      INTO dbo.CanvasApps(id, siteUrl, canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
    SELECT @Name, @logonUrl, @userId;
END
GO
```