# How to access inserted and deleted logical tables with a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to access `inserted` and `deleted` tables using a stored procedure or a function **WITHOUT** using or passing values from a trigger.

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Table (ID) 
VALUES (1)

SELECT * FROM inserted   -> This raises an error
```

Is there a way to do something like this in order to capture the inserted value?

I was able to do this to a query which uses the `MERGE` command as below.

```
MERGE Products AS TARGET
USING UpdatedProducts AS SOURCE ON (TARGET.ProductID = SOURCE.ProductID)  

WHEN MATCHED AND TARGET.ProductName <> SOURCE.ProductName 
                 OR TARGET.Rate <> SOURCE.Rate 
   THEN 
      UPDATE SET TARGET.ProductName = SOURCE.ProductName, 
                 TARGET.Rate = SOURCE.Rate 

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
   THEN 
      INSERT (ProductID, ProductName, Rate) 
      VALUES (SOURCE.ProductID, SOURCE.ProductName, SOURCE.Rate)

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
   THEN 
      DELETE

OUTPUT 
    $action, 
    DELETED.ProductID AS TargetProductID, 
    DELETED.ProductName AS TargetProductName, 
    DELETED.Rate AS TargetRate, 
    INSERTED.ProductID AS SourceProductID, 
    INSERTED.ProductName AS SourceProductName, 
    INSERTED.Rate AS SourceRate;
```

Is there a way to access `inserted` and `deleted` tables for simple SQL queries?

Comment: [You can still use output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147067/output-from-insert-into-stored-procedure). You just need to change your syntax a bit :) [More examples in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Are you trying to: (1) use a stored procedure in a trigger and pass `inserted` and `deleted` to it as implied by the title or (B) trying to capture the changes made by a statement for subsequent processing without using a trigger? The first case can be handled by copying the contents of the pseudotables into temporary tables and passing them to the SP. The second can be handled using an `output` clause (which provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of an `update`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables only in triggers or in the [`output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause of [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements.

In an `insert` statement, the `output` clause can reference the `inserted` table:

```
DECLARE @Ids AS TABLE (id int);

INSERT INTO dbo.Table (ID) 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @Ids(id)
VALUES (1), (2), (3);
```

In an `update` statement, you can reference both the `inserted` table and the deleted table:

```
DECLARE @Ids AS TABLE (oldId int, newId int);

UPDATE dbo.Table 
SET ID = 1
OUTPUT Deleted.ID, Inserted.ID INTO @Ids(oldId, newId);
```

And in a `delete` statement, you can reference the `deleted` table:

```
DECLARE @Ids AS TABLE (id int);

DELETE dbo.Table 
OUTPUT Inserted.ID INTO @Ids(id)
FROM dbo.Table 
WHERE ID IN (1, 2, 3);
```

A `Merge` statement is unique since you have access to both the source table and the `inserted`/`deleted` tables in it's output clause, as demonstrated [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41184310/insert-into-merge-select-sql-server/41184461#41184461).